# Beeline not working when connecting with thriftserver using !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000

Tags: beeline, spark-thriftserver

It is showing the following error :
23/04/28 15:35:40 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: anshuman is not allowed to impersonate hive2 (state=08S01,code=0)

Expecting beeline to connect to thriftserver at localhost:10000

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.